# using the update query with output clause in the dataadapter

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I am using the following query for the sqldataadapter's update command.
 For example `UPDATE employee SET empage=@eage, empdob = @edob WHERE empid = @eid  OUTPUT DELETED.*`

I have to read the output clauses row from the RowUpdated event handler.
How do i do this.

Comment: Its really bad that I am not getting help for this question alone...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use the RowUpdated event to accomplish this.  Since you are using a custom update statement I assume that you are *not* using the SqlDataAdapter.Update() method which is what raises RowUpdated.

Instead you should execute the query using **SqlDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet)**.  The output rows will be stored in the DataSet.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using `SqlDataAdapter.Update()` with custom update command with the output clause. I am able to get on with the `OnRowUpdating` event. However I am not getting the data that was sent from the query using the update event, instead i am getting the new data sent back to me. Currently I am just using a temporary datatable. Any hints on solving my problem further.

Comment: It seems OnRowUpdating is limited to just notifying you of the row that updated, not any additional information your update statement may return.  I recommend using a different approach such as the Fill method that I described above.